# Работа с ячейками PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, таблицы

У меня программа получает данные с оборудования для проверки радиостанций и записывает их в таблицу, несколько ячеек в строке остаются пустыми, т.к. эти данные не получить и вводить их нужно самому вручную.

Возникло два вопроса:

1. как можно поставить условие в ячейку, например если я ввожу значение меньше 50, оно заменяется на «N/R»?
2. Как выяснить содержит ли ячейка какие нибудь данные? После проверки радиостанции заполняется строка и если ячейка пустая, то нужно вывести дефолтное значение.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Можете показать на примере?

```
def get_check_result(self, check_result):

    col = 0

    for param in check_result:

        cell_info = QtTableWidgetItem(str(param)
        self.result_table.setItem(self.row, col, cell_info)
        col += 1
   
    self.row += 1
```

Comment: составьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример (беэ получения данных с оборудования), в котором вы хотите это реализовать и опубликуйте его.

Comment: Вы уже нашли решение или вам сложно составить минимально-воспроизводимый пример ? Вы должны понимать, что я например, не понимаю что такое таблица - это `QTableWidget` или `QTableView`? Какую модель вы используете и т.д ?

Comment: def get_check_result(self, check_result):
    col = 0
    for param in check_result:
        cell_info = QtTableWidgetItem(str(param)
        self.result_table.setItem(self.row, col, cell_info)
        col += 1
   
    self.row += 1

Вот функция которая принимает результаты проверки и заполняет ими таблицу.

В конструкторе: 
self.result_table = QtWidgets.QTable.Widget(self.window)

Comment: Переписал код функции  в вопрос, тут она отображается плохо

Comment: а какую вы СУБД используете? Возможно это можно сделать на уровне бд, или такой вариант не подходит?

Comment: Субд не подключал, пока не было необходимости, каждая проверка выдаёт параметры в мою таблицу, оттуда уже копипастом в ведомость.
Субд планирую реализовать для хранения настроек, чтобы например запоминала с какого ком порта читать. 
Если есть идеи с субд, то скажите.

Comment: Для хранения настроек лучше использовать QSettings

Comment: Я попробую вам помочь, 
но вас надо внимательно прочитать рекомендации, 
которые написаны в причине закрытия вашего вопроса и выполнить их, 
чтобы сообщество нашло возможность переоткрыть ваш вопрос. 
Добавьте немного больше кода в ваш пример. 
Рекомендации как составить [mcve] также рекомендую вам прочитать.

Comment: я уже написал для вас пример, отвечающий на ваши вопросы, но вы почему-то бездействуете. Для решения первого вопроса я использовал Класс QStyledItemDelegate, который предоставляет средства отображения и редактирования элементов данных из модели. Второй вопрос, также не сложно выполнить.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не видел сообщений, решение в ответе не помогло, поэтому бездействовал. Со вторым вопросом разобрался: self.result_table.item(row, col).text() и нужно было отлавливать исключение, так как если ячейка пустая, то вылетала ошибка. А QStyledItemDelegate это видимо то что я ищу. Спасибо вам большое, попробую разобраться. Не знаю почему, но не взлюбил я PyQt, раньше на tkiner все было реализовано, но там таблиц нет...

Comment: Вот что делает лень человеческая, сам себя в тупик загнал и людям не мог доходчиво объяснить что мне надо... А чтобы разобраться нужно было всего лишь углубиться в документацию, почитать, перевести. Через событие itemChanged все решилось за пол часа. Спасибо всем за советы и за желание помочь, разобрался, все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете QTableWidget, то для тонкой настройки поведения ячеек можно наследовать QTableWidgetItem и сделать с наследниками все, что вы хотите.

Например:

1. как можно поставить условие в ячейку, например если я ввожу значение меньше 50, оно заменяется на «N/R»?

```
class MyWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super.__init__(self)
        self.setValue(value)

    def setValue(self, value):
        # если value число, то приведем его к int и проверим значение
        if isnumeric(value) and int(value) < 50:
            super.setText('N/R')
        else:
            super.setText(value)

    def value(self, defaultValue=''):
        # Если text не пустой, то возвращаем его значение, иначе вернем дефолтное
        return self.text() if self.text() else defaultValue
```

Теперь можно плодить соответствующие объекты и наполнять ими какой-нибудь QTаbleWidget

```
self.result_table.setItem(row, col, MyWidgetItem(param))
```

2. Как выяснить содержит ли ячейка какие нибудь данные? После проверки радиостанции заполняется строка и если ячейка пустая, то нужно вывести дефолтное значение.

```
# метод какого-то класса
def getTableCellValue(self):
    item = self.result_table.getItem(row, col)
    # Ячейка нашего типа?
    if isinstance(item, MyWidgetItem):
        cell_info = (MyWidgetItem)self.result_table.getItem(row, col)
        cell_value = cell_info.value(defaultValue="nichego_nyet")
```